# Load testing for real lifecycle

Tags: cloud, load-testing

I need a load testing tool that we can use to load an entire page and it will run and execute the js/ajax on the page.

I have tried several online tools and most of them seem to make the http request and then subsequent images but they are missing the firing of the js items which then miss the real load on the system

Any ideas or recommendations of a cloud based tool that will run real webpages (including js items)

Comment: Are you willing to try out something that is still a work-in-progress?  (i.e. beta-quality)

Comment: Cmerril, I sure am. Let me know where to sign up. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Google plugin for Jmeter (version 1.1.0 to be released shortly) on top of Apache Jmeter version 2.9 (already released).

Version 1.1.0 of the plugin will include WebDriver sampler that you many need.

Download it as soon as it's released from: https://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/

Download the main tool from: http://jmeter.apache.org/